# How to handle 404 errors on js file using bokeh serve

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Might be out of my league here so apologies if I am missing something obvious. I developed a web app (`GEEapp`) which works beautifully locally and I am now trying to upload it on a web server to share it with some collaborators. The folder `GEEapp` contains a file named `main.py` and I run it using `bokeh serve GEEapp` from the root directory. One of the first function pulls data from a sqlite file and prints the expected output to the terminal, but right after - when the actual plotting starts - I get 404 errors on the javascript resources:

```
2020-06-08 16:03:08,161 404 GET /GEEappstatic/js/bokeh.min.js?v=57d29d5936e494351385d736f792154c 
2020-06-08 16:03:08,545 404 GET /GEEappstatic/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=fdb1f42cceaade9062de57963cac654c 
2020-06-08 16:03:08,552 404 GET /GEEappstatic/js/bokeh-gl.min.js?v=c376f0736800259be44cb1aed39a6cc3 
2020-06-08 16:03:08,563 404 GET /GEEappstatic/js/bokeh-tables.min.js?v=0a7f930d4b0805283dfba427bb3d0dae
```

The result is an empty window, but `cursor.title` is read and displayed as my browser’s tab title (e.g. ‘Time series’ - see code below). Also I find the `GEEappstatic` very suspicious - shouldn’t it be `GEEapp/static` instead?

How is it possible to make the path to the js files right? This question was also posted [here](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bokeh-serve-error-404-for-js-ressources/5708)

```py
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, figure, gmap
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6, Category20, RdYlGn, Turbo, Cividis256
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, GMapPlot, GMapOptions, HoverTool, TapTool, Range1d, Select, Dropdown, RadioGroup, LinearAxis, RangeSlider, MultiSelect, BooleanFilter, CDSView
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs, Div, DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from bokeh.tile_providers import get_provider, Vendors
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Circle
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.themes import built_in_themes
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
import bokeh.resources

where = 'WHERE eruption=\'Shinmoedake2011\''
data, points, eruption, events = loadData(where)

#...
# code
#...


curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "Time series"
```

Comment: What version of Bokeh? Do you have the same issue with directory-style app exampls in the GitHub repo?

Comment: Thanks for your answer bigreddot. Indeed the examples do not work and it is related to some server configuration - you pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Is this on Windows? All the examples are run (successfully) on Linux and OSX almost daily by either a person or automated CI

Comment: No it's on a university web server. There were apparently problems in how the IT person set the path + some Apache config. I can run my app and all the examples locally without problem. IT team is still figuring things out. I initially thought the problem came from me. Sorry for the bother and thanks for the fast answer

Comment: @e5k I have the same problem. What should I tell my IT people?

Comment: @LeeviL, the IT team spent hours on it and ended up reinstalling the whole server... Sorry for the bad news! In the end I just gave them the link to [this page](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#deployment-scenarios) and they managed to figure it out.